# How to show all contents of current subtree and fold all the other subtrees?

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode, outline

When using org build subtree navigation functions to move around, I want to show all the content of current one recursively, and hide any other subtrees that having a higher or same level of the current one. How to achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edited in response to first comment*

Not quite sure if this is what you want, but here's a function that will show the current subtree (and its children) and fold all other headings to their top level:

```
(defun ess/org-show-just-me (&rest _)
  "Fold all other trees, then show entire current subtree."
  (interactive)
  (org-overview)
  (org-reveal)
  (org-show-subtree))
```

Now you can add advices for each command you want to use this function together with:

```
(advice-add 'org-forward-heading-same-level :after #'ess/org-show-just-me)
(advice-add 'org-backward-heading-same-level :after #'ess/org-show-just-me)
```

Another alternative is to use `org-narrow-to-subtree` to hide all other content than the current subtree. It is bound to `C-x n s` by default. To go back, use `widen`, bound to `C-x n w`. A great alternative is [narrow-or-widen-dwim](http://endlessparentheses.com/emacs-narrow-or-widen-dwim.html).

You could add `widen` followed by `org-narrow-to-subtree` to a function and create this as an advice in the same way as the example above.

Comment: I know about `org-narrow-to-subtree`, but I want to show and hide content automatically every time I use a build in function like `org-forward-heading-same-level` to move around. I'll read about `narrow-or-widen-dwim` soon. Thanks !

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer and hopefully it does what you want.

Comment: This helped a lot to find a workaroud for [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58167/org-sort-expands-all-subtrees-and-drawers/59045#59045).

Answer (score 0):

There is strange parameters in (org-reveal), it require '(4) to be passed to works right, idk why.

For Org mode:

```lisp
(defun my/org-fold-hide-other ()
     "Hide other headers and reveal current and don't hide headers and text in opened ones."
     (interactive)
     (save-excursion
       (org-overview) ;; hide others
       (org-reveal '(4)))) ;; reveal current place appropriate)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (local-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'my/org-fold-hide-other))
```

For outline mode:

```lisp
(defun my/outline-hide-other ()
     "Hide other headers and don't hide headers and text in opened ones.
like (outline-hide-other)"
     (interactive)
     (save-excursion
       (outline-hide-sublevels 1) ;; hide all, set level to required!
       (outline-show-children) ;; show headers, not shure how and wehere,
       (outline-back-to-heading t) ;; to header in depths
       (outline-show-entry) ;; show local text
       (outline-up-heading 1 t) ;; go upper
       (while ( > (funcall outline-level) 1) ;; while not at first header
           (outline-show-entry)
           (outline-show-children) ;; show subheaders
           (outline-up-heading 1 t) ;; go upper
           )))
   (add-hook 'outline-mode-hook (lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'my/outline-hide-other))
```