# How can I expand everything recursively under the current heading / element in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Hoping the question is not too brief, I'm assuming this is a fairly common operation - but I can't seem to find anything in the docs about this.

Comment: By /everything/ do you mean all subheadings, source blocks, property blocks, logbooks, and archived branches?

Comment: Pressing Shift + tab?

Comment: Shift tab expands everything in the document.

Comment: I would imagine that the answer in this related thread does what you want and then something extra that you do not want:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29304/how-to-show-all-contents-of-current-subtree-and-fold-all-the-other-subtrees  Perhaps you can just eliminate the last step that you don't want ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for this as well.  It took me a while to find since it's not mentioned anywhere in the docs, but it appears that the `org-show-subtree` command does exactly what you want.

If you use Doom Emacs, it's bound to `z O`.

Answer (score 0):

`org-show-subtree` was exactly I was looking for. I just want to add that the command was changed to `org-fold-show-subtree` (`org-show-subtree` is an obsolete command (as of Org version 9.6); use `org-fold-show-subtree` instead)

Comment: What is that "9.6"? Is that an Org release number or something? If you know, maybe mention it in the answer. (If you don't know, that's fine.) Thx.

Comment: 9.6 is the Org version, yes, visible in the variable `org-version`. Btw, there's also `org-fold-show-branches`, which only shows nested headings, but not text in them—useful for a more compact overview. Alas, Org doesn't appear to have a function for showing headings and text, but with properties kept hidden—which would be helpful for people who slap metadata on everything.

Comment: You can add an after-advice to any such commands using `org-hide-drawer-all`.

Comment: @NickD Brilliant, thanks.